# How can I get my fetch to stop aborting (the data is confirmed to be in the repo)?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, fetch-api

I have confirmed by clicking on the URL that the data I want is indeed in the repo in which it is supposed to be, but when I run the web code in debug mode and click on this web page, I get an abort fetching component error.

Perhaps I'm loading in the data incorrectly? In any case, I'm not sure what is wrong, as the data is indeed in the repo and I'm trying to load it into a json and eventually into a React chart.

I get the below error message:

```
Exception has occurred: Error: Abort fetching component for route: "/dashboard/playground"
  at handleCancelled (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/shared/lib/router/router.js:558:19)
    at _callee6$ (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/shared/lib/router/router.js:2157:17)
    at tryCatch (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:45:40)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:274:22)
    at prototype.<computed> [as next] (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:97:21)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/shared/lib/router/router.js:72:24)
    at _next (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/shared/lib/router/router.js:94:9)
```

See my code:

***playIndex.tsx***

```
export async function getServerSideProps() /*= async () =>*/ {
    const res = await fetch("http://localhost:8081/api/my10y");
    const my10y = await res.json();
    return {
      props: { my10y },
    };
  };

  export function MY10YTest(props: { my10y: any[]/*{ DateTime: Key | null | undefined; Value: string | null | undefined; }*/; }) {
  return (
    <div>
      {props.my10y.map((p/*: { DateTime: Key | null | undefined; Value: boolean | ReactChild | ReactFragment | ReactPortal | null | undefined; }*/) => {
        return (
          <div key={p.DateTime}>
            <p>
              {p.Value}%
            </p>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

***playground.tsx***

```
import { /*useState,*/ ReactElement } from 'react';

// material-ui
import {
  Grid,
} from '@mui/material';

// project import
import Layout from 'layout';
import Page from 'components/Page';
import AnalyticsDataCard from 'components/cards/statistics/AnalyticsDataCard';
import MY01YChart from 'sections/dashboard/analytics/MY01YChart'
import MY02YChart from 'sections/dashboard/analytics/MY02YChart';
import MY10YChart from 'sections/dashboard/analytics/MY10YChart';
import { getServerSideProps, MY10YTest } from 'pages/api/playIndex';


// ==============================|| DASHBOARD - ANALYTICS ||============================== //

const DashboardAnalytics = async () => {
  const serverSideProps = await getServerSideProps();

  return (
    <Page title="Consumer Price Index (CPI) Dashboard">
      <Grid container rowSpacing={4.5} columnSpacing={3}>
        {/* row 1 */}
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={4} lg={3}>
          <AnalyticsDataCard title="Treasury Bill (1 Year) Interest Rate" count="23" percentage={-95.3} isLoss={true}>
            <MY01YChart />
          </AnalyticsDataCard>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={4} lg={3}>
          <AnalyticsDataCard title="Treasury Bill (2 Year) Interest Rate" count="23" percentage={-95.3} isLoss={true}>
            <MY02YChart />
          </AnalyticsDataCard>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={4} lg={3}>
          <AnalyticsDataCard title="Treasury Bond(10 Year) Interest Rate" count="23" percentage={-95.3} isLoss={true}>
            <MY10YChart />
          </AnalyticsDataCard>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={4} lg={3}>
          <AnalyticsDataCard title="Treasury Bond(10 Year) Interest Rate" count="23" percentage={-95.3} isLoss={true}>
            <MY10YTest my10y={serverSideProps.props.my10y} />
          </AnalyticsDataCard>
        </Grid>

        <Grid item md={8} sx={{ display: { sm: 'none', md: 'block', lg: 'none' } }} />
      </Grid>
    </Page>
  );
};

DashboardAnalytics.getLayout = function getLayout(page: ReactElement) {
  return <Layout>{page}</Layout>;
};

export default DashboardAnalytics;
```

Comment: Two things: 1) that is not how `getServerSideProps` is supposed to be used in Next.js (see https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-server-side-props); 2) In React, side-effect like fetching data from an API should be done inside a `useEffect` (see https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html).